# Read data from Firebase to swift3 EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following firebase database
[image]

This is how I add data into the database

[image]

And this is how I try to get the data out of Database but I get this error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your force unwrap is saying that the dictionary should only consist of `String: String`. But as you can see, the value for the key `value` is an integer, which will be parsed as an `NSNumber` according [to the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDataSnapshot?authuser=0) so `String: AnyObject` is what you want to unwrap as.

```
let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
```

A little bit of safer code would be:

```
guard let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    else {
    return
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I figured it out already :) thanks though

Comment: Safer code would be to use a `guard` or a `let if`, both `as` or `as!` will cause a crash if there is a value mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

The error appears because my database value is Integer and I want to read it as String.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer to your own question or just further information? Because this does not provide an answer to your issue.

Comment: @rmaddy just info

Comment: Then please delete this "answer" and update your question. Only post an answer for an actual answer to a question.